# CC4 ALWAYS shows the wrong printer

Tags: windows-10, brother-printer

The CCR shows Model MFC-8910DW whenever I fire it up.  That printer is long gone.  How do I get it to show the correct printer without having to waste time until I realize I am trying to use a printer that doesn't exist here.  The new printer is L5900DW.   **How do I make the 5900 the default, in fact the only Model up there in the top field?**

Comment: [Windows 10 How to remove printer from list](https://www.google.com/search?&q=windows+10+remove+printer+from+list)

Comment: Is it `CC4` or `CCR`?